# Solution for the nonhomogeneous Recurrence relation.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

How can we get the solution for the following nonhomogeneous Recurrence Relations:
$$y_{n}+by_{n-1}+ay_{n-2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{b^2-4a}}[(\frac{\sqrt{b^2-4a}-b}{ 2 })^{n+1}-  (\frac{-\sqrt{b^2-4a}-b}{ 2 })^{n+1} ]$$ with $y_0=d,y_1=c-2bd$, where $a,b,c,d$ are some real numbers.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: first step: let $z^n=y_n$. then whats $y_{n-1}$? $y_{n-2}$?